# Bootloader installation failed

Tags: boot, dual-boot, bootloader

I was trying to install Ubuntu Studio 21.10 as my second OS. Cleaned the hard drive, created bootable USB disk. Booted it up and began to install Ubuntu. At the end the installation program said this:

> Installation Failed Bootloader installation error The bootloader could
> not be installed. The installation command grub-install
> --target-i386pc --recheck --force /dev/sda returned code 1.

I don't know if this will help, but when I was creating a USB disk, Rufus said that version of grub required for this distro is 2.04 but I have 2.06.

Comment: You haven't provided any release details; but all supported releases of Ubuntu on this site use grub `2.04` (or older).

Comment: Hello. What version are you trying to install?

Comment: I am trying to install Ubuntu Studio 21.10

Comment: Ubuntu 21.10 (inc. Studio) uses `grub2 | 2.04-1ubuntu47          | impish` and not grub 2.06

Comment: So I need to get grub2?

Comment: Grub for a decade+ has been grub2... It's just called `grub` though the package & version technically is `grub2`..   2.04/2.06 is the Grub version 2 found in package `grub2` (which is incompatible with the original version; thus package name change)  Ubuntu 21.10 doesn't use `grub 2.06` though as my prior comment lists the package version for *impish* or 21.10  What is your other OS, why do you have `grub` 2.06 when it's not related to Ubuntu Studio 21.10 ??

Comment: I am sorry, but I am very new to Linux, and don't understand much. Can you tell me what I need to do, if you have any clues on the cause of the problem?

Comment: Your provided *facts* do not add up; the 2.06 you mention in Ubuntu refers to off-topic `grub2 | 2.06-2ubuntu5           | jammy` that you say you're not using.  Please provide details of the other OS & why you're using grub 2.06 when Ubuntu Studio 21.10 uses 2.04-1ubuntu47.  Please answer prior comment.

Comment: I used Rufus to create boot USB, it has preinstalled grub 2.06. It asked if I want to find a 2.04 version online and I said yes. I am using Windows 10 as my main OS.

Comment: Thanks I understand now; you're not *cloning* the ISO to thumb-drive, but using the `rufus` program to re-work the ISO when writing to thumb-drive (a *clone* means it would have the version found in my posts; ie. `2.04-1ubuntu47` for 21.10).  Sorry I'm not familiar with `rufus` as I don't use it.

Comment: So I need to use another software? Witch one?

Comment: there is nothing wrong with `rufus`, but I don't write ISOs from windows machines so have no experience with it. You'll have to wait for help from others (not me!)

Comment: Thank you anyway.

Comment: Sounds as if you try to install in wrong boot-mode, you should install in UEFI-mode, not legacy-mode. You need to boot installer in UEFI-mode, how you boot is how you install.

Comment: Will try this, thanks

Comment: @guiverc In the boot selection-part in the program you can choose ```Grub 2.06```. However if you just want to make a bootable USB-stick you just leave it on ```disk or iso image```. Then click ```select``` to the right of that to select your iso. So what tree__dude wrote makes sense.

Comment: @mook765 It worked! Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad your problem is solved - in future please include software/hardware details as related to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I took a look and tried to make a screenshot in Windows. When I tried to open it in Kubuntu it couldn't open the .png, so I have no screenshot for you. Let me try to explain: in bootselection (red square) choose `disk or iso-image`. On the right of this you can select (green/yellow oval) which .iso you want to 'burn' to your selected usb-device. You let the rest of the settings as they are. They will not be the same as in the picture. (In `Partition Scheme` will show `MBR`  and `Target System` will be `BIOS or UEFI`). Choose your `Volume Label` e.g. Ubuntu Studio 21.10). Then you click `start`.
The .iso contains the right version of grub, so don't worry about that. Just let Rufus do its thing. That is all there is to it. 
Then of course, start from USB, install your OS. It should work just fine now.
PS. I use Ventoy to make USB media. I install Ventoy to the USB-device and just drag 'n drop bootable .isos (yes, more than 1, Windows, Linux, Haiku, DOS, TempleOS, Hiren's Boot CD, Grub2Win, GParted.iso it all works) to it. When starting up my USB-stick I can choose which OS (because it has more than 1) I want to start.
Found a picture , thanks Dr. Google, and added it/edited my answer.[image]